# Self-Screenshot producing webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, screenshot

How would I go about trying to have my website allow a user to save a portion of my website ( such as a single div) as an image. Or, how could my website produce a self screenshot? I have a combination of images like,

```
<div> <img A><img B><img C> </div>
```

But I would like to give my user the opportunity to download the entire div as a single image rather than 3 separate images. The div content is dynamically produced, so I can't just combine the image files together.

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Answer (score 0):

You would save the whole div as an image the way you want the user to download it. And the below the div or even inside it create and put a download button to download that new image of the div you created saved. The button is really a form like below.

```
<form method="get" action="image.jpg">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

Ask if you need anymore help and I hope this helps! Littleswany

Comment: This seems to me to be a restatement of the question.  All that's missing is "How do I..." at the front.  lastr2d2's comment, though, guides to an answer. ;)

Comment: Is that better @JeremyMiller